# Excel Counting rows that have values in a definite number of columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a worksheet in excel with 30 rows and near 80 columns. Each cell can have a positive number or "-". I want to count the number of rows that have a positive number in less than 10 columns (without pivot tables or other bypassed solution, just a formula in one cell).

Comment: Are you not open to a row of helper formulas?  With 80 columns, you may well run into the character limit on a single formula without them.

Answer (score 0):

If you do allow a single helper column (you can hide it), put this formula into the cell to the right of your first row's last data cell, where **x** needs to be replaced with the last column having data:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:x1,"<>-")<10,1,0)
```

Then copy this cell into all cells below this one, for all rows you have.

Then calculate this columns' sum. Voilá.

Comment: Thanks, but I would rather not use a helper column. My worksheet is already to convoluted to add another column (even if I hide it). Is there any other way ?

Comment: Well, in principle yes, but I doubt Excel would let you do this for all rows, there's a maximum of chars you can enter. =IF(COUNTIF(A1:x1,"<>-")<10,1,0) + IF(COUNTIF(A2:x2,"<>-")<10,1,0) + IF(COUNTIF(A3:x3,"<>-")<10,1,0) + ... + IF(COUNTIF(An:xn,"<>-")<10,1,0)